# Why does the model binder need an empty constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need some help with some fundamentals here...

I have this controller that serves up my view with an instance of a class (at least that's how I think it works). So since I am giving my view a new instance of the object, why does it have to create a NEWer one for the model binding for my post back?  Please look at the below example.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(){
  int hi = 5;
  string temp = "yo";
  MyModel foo = new MyModel(hi, temp);
  return View(foo);
}
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(MyModel foo){
  MyModel poo = foo;
  if(poo.someString == laaaa)
    return RedirctToAction("End", "EndCntrl", poo);
  else
    throw new Exception();
}

View:
@model myApp.models.MyModel

@html.EditorFor(m => m.hi) 
<input type="submit" value="hit"/>

Model:
public class MyModel {
 public int hi {get; set;}
 public string someString {get; set;}
 public  stuff(int number, string laaaa){
  NumberforClass = number;
  someString = laaaa;
 }
}
```

Why do I need a blank constructor? Furthermore, if I had an parameterless constructor, why would `poo.someString` change by the time I got to `RedirctToAction("End", "EndCntrl", poo)`?

Comment: Read this for basics of how model binding works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: What empty constructor are you talking about? The only constructor I see in your example is "stuff(int number, string laaaa)"

Comment: Please make your code consistent, only post stuff that actually compiles. `class stuff != class MyModel`, `hi != NumberforClass `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do I need a blank constructor?

because of

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(MyModel foo){ ... }
```

You asked the binder to give you a concrete instance on Post, so the binder needs to create that object for you. Your original object does not persist between the GET and POST actions, only (some of) its properties live on as HTML fields. Thats what "HTTP is stateless" means.

It becomes a little more obvious when you use the lower level

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{ 
      var Foo = new MyModel();
      // load the properties from the FormCollection yourself
}
```

> why would poo.someString change by the time I got to `RedirctToAction("End", "EndCntrl", poo)`?

Because `someString` isn't used in your View. So it will always be blank when you get the new model back. To change that:

```
@model myApp.models.MyModel    
@html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeString) 

@html.EditorFor(m => m.hi) 
<input type="submit" value="hit"/>
```

this will store the value as a hidden field in the HTML and it will be restored for you on POST.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct connection between model you pass to view and model that you receive in request. In ultimate case the code for initial request and response will run in different instance of IIS or even different machines.

So when request come back ASP.Net MVC need to recreate all objects (controller, model,...). Having default constructor allows run-time to create new object without knowledge of particular arguments to your custom constructor.

Side note: Similar reconstruction for constructor exist for generics where you can only specify `where T:new()` for default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by the question but instead have you tried this:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(MyModel foo){
  if(foo.someString == "laaaa")
    return RedirctToAction("End", "EndCntrl", foo);
  else
    throw new Exception();
}
```

You only need a parameterless constructor if you added a parameterized constructor.

Ex: MyObject item = new MyObject();

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need a parameter less constructor as long you do not define any constructors. If you define a constructor with parameters, you need then a parameter less constructor as it is the one used by the model binder..

when you postback the values, the binder will map your request in a typed object, it first creates the object, and then tries to map your posted values to some property.

If you  can not have a parameter less constructor... if code is not Under your control, then you have to create a Custom binder.

Comment: It does need a parameterless ctor.  The fact that the c# compiler adds one for you automatically if you don't define your own ctors does not mean model binding doesn't require one.

Comment: Yah yah... that's what I implicitely said ! But maybe you are such a professor ?

Comment: No you don't imply it anywhere, in fact you imply otherwise.  And this isn't an academic thing, some people still don't know that the c# compiler will insert a default constructor for you.